# vim emulation extension in VScode causing problems

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim-plugin

I've been using VS Code in "VIM mode" for years now without a problem. I'm on v1.46 now. I fired it up today and immediately couldn't type and other keys like escape failed to register. In the lower left corner, I'd intermittently see the following:

[image]

I went into extensions and disabled the Vim Emulator which now allow me to edit the file normally... without the vim functionality, of course.

I saw a bug filed through GitHub that looked like it might have addressed it, but it was closed due to lack of info provided.

Any ideas what might be going on or how I can get my vim functionality back?

### **UPDATE**

Here's a bit more info:

- I reinstalled and updated both VSCode and plugin - same behavior
- Sometimes the whole thing failed from the get and other times (after restarting), it seemed to fail 1 key at a time - for example I'd be typing along and then all of a sudden hitting backspace produces an error message in the lower right corner to the effect of `command 'extension.vim_backspace' not found` - here's the closed issue on github - https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/22365 for that specific message, but I also got  errors with the escape and other keys
- I also tried switching to NeoVim (on mac) which I *thought* was working, but eventually ended up going the same route (`esc` stopped working first typically)

Comment: Try updating the extension and vscode. Does the plugin fails completely or certain features only? Which features are working? Also provide the gilhub issue link you refered.

Comment: @HeisAif - See updates in OP - thanks!

Comment: You tried neovim as a standalone application or neovim support by vscodevim plugin?

Comment: Yes, it seems to work fine outside of VSCode... although I haven't sat using it for an entire coding session - just testing. How would I go about using it supported by vscodevim plugin?

Comment: Neovim is working? But you wrote *eventually ended up going the same route*, can you clarify? To use neovim support you can search `neovim` in vscode setting and enable it but It may not solve your issue.

Comment: Neovim is working when I launch it from the terminal. Using it through the Neo Vim extension within VSCode is what I was referring to when I said it eventually ended up going the same route. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score -2):

I was having a similar problem with Vim in VS Code, and I noticed at the bottom-left when it reads `--NORMAL--` or `--VISUAL--` I typed the letter "i" and `--INSERT--` appeared and allows me to type. I typed "i" because when I could type that is what I saw in the bottom-left corner of the screen.

Hope this is helpful.